# Prove that for a convergent sequence with no max, sup(an)=L

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ be a convergent sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}=L$. Suppose $a_n$ has no maximum. Prove that $\sup{(a_n)}=L$.

In a similar way, Let ${a_n}$ be a convergent sequence such that $\lim_{n \to \infty}=L$. Suppose $a_n$ has no minimum. Prove that $\inf{(a_n)}=L$.

I'm having some trouble formalizing this idea... i did try:

$a_n$ converges to $L \Rightarrow$ let $\varepsilon \gt 0.$ for some $n \geq N\in\Bbb N, \ |a_n-L|\lt \varepsilon.$ From the completeness axiom, any non-empty bounded sequence has a $\sup \Rightarrow$ let $M=sup(a_n)$.
For any $\varepsilon \gt 0\ $ :   $\ M- \varepsilon \leq a_n \lt M$

Now im pretty confused. how should i link M to L, the limit? Is this even the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Clearly $M\geq L$, as the definition of limit implies that *no* upper bound can be less than $L$.

If $k$ is such that $a_k>L$, then there are only finitely many terms of the sequence that are greater than or equal to $a_k$, and one of them is going to be a maximum. And if no such $k$ exists, but there is an $\ell$ such that $a_\ell = L$, then that is a maximum.

By the above paragraph, assuming that there is no maximum implies that $a_n<L$ for all $n$, which again means that $L$ is an upper bound for the sequence. And since $M$ is the *least* upper bound, we have $M\leq L$.

Comment: Thank you! that helped make things clearer

Answer (score 3):

Let $M=\sup_na_n$

The supremum exists since $a_n$ is bounded.

By the know property of supremum we have that,for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ you can find a subsequence of distinct(Why??) points(since $a_n$ has no maximum) $a_{m_n}$ of $a_n$ such that $M-\frac{1}{n}<a_{m_n}\leq M$

So $a_{m_n} \to M$ and also $a_{m_n} \to L$(since every subsequence of a convergent sequence has the same limit as the original sequence)and by uniqueness of limit we have that $L=M$

Comment: I think that you should point out the fact that such subsequence exist because the sequence has no maximum should be carefully justify by the OP as an exercise.

Comment: @Herman i know that's why i did not mentioned it in my proof..it is a good exercise for the O.P to use the property if supremum.,,,i added a ''why'' for the O.P so show it.

Comment: Moreover, the subsequence don't need to be of distinct points (such a subsequence may not exist by the way).

Comment: @Herman..since the sequence is bounded(by convergence) above and has no maximum then i think there exists a subsequence if distinct points converging  to $M$

Comment: Maybe, but this is not crucial. The important thing is that there is a subsequence $(a_{m_n})$ s.t. $M-\frac{1}{n}\leq a_{m_n}\leq M$, not that $a_{m_n}\neq a_{m_k}$ for all $n\neq k$.

Comment: @Herman..  Since the sequence has not a maximum then there must exist a subsequence with distinct points,,because if every subsequence is eventualy constant(or constant) and satisfies the above inequality for every natural number then we would have that exists a  term $a_m$ such that $a_m=M$ and then the sequence would have a maximum(which is not allowed by hypothesis)

Comment: Marios. Correct me if wrong. There is no need for {a_n}  to be infinite, means: There is a subsequence a_n in any case that converges to sup (a_n).Agreed the no maximum assures infinitely many distinct a_n Is this essential to guarantee that there is a subsequence a_{n_k} converging to sup (a_n)?Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSzilas i do not follow..can you make specific  what your question is exactly?

Comment: Marios.I try. My post, which I feel a bit uneasy about, does not need infinitely many distinct a_n. Theorem: Every non empty set A, reals, has a supremum. No mention of infinitely many elements. They construct a sequence  that converges to sup. Your thoughts?

Comment: @PeterSzilas  if the sequence has finitely many elements,thus take finitely many values,then one of these values would be a maximum (since the supremum of a finite sets of reals is the maximum)which is not allow by hypothesis on the post..

Comment: Marios.True. This is ruled out by the no maximum. Since there seems to be(exists!) a subsequence converging to sup in any case no need to construct one for this problem, one can assume it: there is a subsequence converging to sup( which could be the maximum if only finitely many distinct elements). Just want to avoid constructing one if it is a given.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) $L\leq \sup_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n$.

Indeed, if $L>\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n$, then, if $0<\varepsilon<L-\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n$, by definition of the convergence, there is $N$ s.t. $$\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n<L-\varepsilon <a_N,$$ which is not possible.

> 2) $L=\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n$.

Suppose $L<\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n$. In particular, if $0<\varepsilon <\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n-L$, by definition of the convergence, there is $N$ s.t. $$a_k\leq L+\varepsilon<\sup_{n\in \mathbb N}a_n,$$
for all $k\geq N$. Therefore $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n=\sup_{n=1,...,N}a_n,$$
and thus, there is $k\in\{1,...,N\}$ s.t. $$a_k=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n.$$
Contradiction with the fact that $(a_n)$ has no maximum.